# Error while creating oracle sequence using datatype BIGINT

Tags: oracle, sequence, bigint

Have an error while trying to create Oracle sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE HR.order_entry_id
             AS BIGINT START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE SEQUENCE HR.USER_PROFILE_SEQ
             AS BIGINT START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1
```

> Error at line 1 ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Is there an issue with this create statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `bigint` is not a data type in Oracle.
Second, the `create sequence` DDL statement does not accept an `as <<data type>>` clause.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE hr.order_entry_id
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
```

Since you're not overriding the default `start with` or `increment by`, you can also just do

```
CREATE SEQUENCE hr.order_entry_id
```